# Proper way of constructing sampling distribution

Tags: sampling-distribution

While the proper way of constructing the sampling distribution would be to repeatedly sample from population with unknown parameters, I'm not convinced it is the case in practice. Surveys performed in real life is always one-off questionaires that collect a bunch of samples, e.g. one sample of sized n. If they are to construct the sampling distribution, do they just subsample that single sample? Yet I'm not convinced it would be representative of the population. Thus, my questions are multi-folded:

i) In practice, do people construct sampling distribution just from a single sample with sized N (by repeatatively drawing samples sized <N? Instead of doing repeatative sampling from the population? If it's the former approach, won't the estimate become bias towards the mother sample sized N?

ii) In practice, do people collect one-off sample of sized N and do their analysis or multiple samples from the population?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What’s an example where you’ve seen a sampling distribution calculated? How was it calculated?

Answer (score 0):

I can speak to the reality of sampling versus best practice from my job experience working in a corporate marketing business unit.  I have been part of projects that create samples for marketing surveys and for experiments testing changes to pricing and procedures.

Your first question is whether we constructed multiple samples or a single sample to calculate distribution: the short answer is yes because software has made this super simple if you have the data clean and accessible.  For most purposes, sales data was the response variable of choice and it was in the company's best interest to keep that data clean and accessible.  We used proprietary software and created a Shiny R dashboard that was pulling multiple samples from the "population" every time we needed a distribution to compare to our experiment sample.

For surveys, which are costly no matter if you have one-off focused surveys versus constantly "on" surveys, we would not collect multiple samples.  It's actually infuriating how often myself or anyone from data science would bring up bias and attempt to produce examples of well-balanced samples but for reasons usually due to time and money, the biased and skewed samples were deemed good enough.